# octave libs not linking properly

Tags: c++, octave, ubuntu-18.04

I built octave-4.4.0 and created binaries and libs in my own path instead of /usr/local, and i am able to link my cpp program through CMakeList and its working fine.

the same octave folder when i shipped to different ubuntu in another machine and try linking the cpp program as same way through CMakeList i am unable to do execute the binary. i am getting this error. I moved octave by tar (with symlink)

> error: feval: function 'pkg' not found terminate called after throwing
>   an instance of 'octave::execution_exception'

please help me to resolve this

Comment: Check manual [ld library path](https://gerardnico.com/os/linux/ld_library_path)

Comment: its pointing to path where by libs are available                                                                                          liboctave.so.5 => /home/octbuild/Projects/tool/octave-4.4.0/lib/octave/4.4.0/liboctave.so.5 (0x00007f811fe51000)
 liboctinterp.so.5 => /home/octbuild/Projects/tool/octave-4.4.0/lib/octave/4.4.0/liboctinterp.so.5 (0x00007f811eafd000)